# Directory Nonexistent when Attaching VSCode to running Docker Container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have a running docker container. I was previously able to connect to this container. During use, I was disconnected. Attempts to reconnect to the docker container (or other variations thereof) are unsuccessful. I've included the logs for this below.

```
[225 ms] Dev Containers 0.275.1 in VS Code 1.75.0 (e2816fe719a4026ffa1ee0189dc89bdfdbafb164).
[225 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[227 ms] Setting up container: container_name_redacted
[227 ms] Host: host_redacted
[230 ms] Start: Run: host_redacted /bin/sh
[251 ms] Start: Run in host: id -un
[3684 ms] name_redacted
[3685 ms] 
[3685 ms] Start: Run in host: cat /etc/passwd
[3702 ms] Start: Run in host: echo ~
[3719 ms] /home/name_redacted
[3720 ms] 
[3721 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/name_redacted/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/e2816fe719a4026ffa1ee0189dc89bdfdbafb164/node'
[3738 ms] 
[3738 ms] 
[3739 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/name_redacted/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/vscode-remote-containers-server-0.275.1.js'
[3756 ms] 
[3756 ms] 
[3769 ms] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[3770 ms] userEnvProbe: not found in cache
[3770 ms] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/bash
[3852 ms] userEnvProbe PATHs:
Probe:     '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games'
Container: None
[3871 ms] Start: Run in Host: docker inspect --type container /redacted_container_name
[3933 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[3933 ms] Start: Run in Host: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[3999 ms] Server API version: 1.41
[4047 ms] Command failed: /bin/sh -c cat >'/tmp/devcontainer-config-91de0ba6-e023-476c-b3a0-df813264bd3f.json'
[4047 ms] /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /tmp/devcontainer-config-91de0ba6-e023-476c-b3a0-df813264bd3f.json: Directory nonexistent
[4047 ms] Exit code 2
```

It looks like it cannot access the /tmp/ directory. I've tried mapping this directory to the container using -v. I've also tried opening up permissions. I've tried creating the container specific to my user. I've tried using privileged parameter. I'm at a loss here.